# How to handle scenarios that "should not happen" in Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am wondering what is the best practice in Spock for scenarios that are exceptional or underfined situations. One that should normally not happen.

---

**EXAMPLE**:
Let's say in our API, there are two mutually exclusive fields. When both provided the result of some calculations is undefined, which in practice boils to some arbitrary handling - like giving precedence to one of them.

On a higher level that will lead to exception and a proper http response eventually. But in some local (unit) area a piece of code will still be executed against both.

When writing unit tests, I'd like to cover (record) also the current behaviour for this (atm) impossible corner case.

---

So far I just resorted to a proper comment, either in the test case name or somewhere else. But the question is: **what would be the best/idiomatic Spock practice for documenting those scenarios**? I mean something similar using || for separating expected arguments in `where` clause.

Comment: Please provide a complete sample class and the current version of the corresponding test illustrating your situation. I cannot compile and debug ambiguous prose and also do not feel so inclined to speculate what your code might look like. If I can see the code, though, I am confident that I or someone else can make one or multiple good suggestions about how to handle the situation.

Comment: If places rely on the behaviour, make it a regular test. If it has no relevance, put a comment in the function and if you fear someone might rely on the behaviour put some assert in the function. IMHO this demands nothing special from spock.

Comment: It sounds to me like your API needs some input validation to make sure that you don't run into undefined behavior, or some internal checks that throw an `IllegalStateException` if an internal invariant is violated.